# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Missing defines

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have done below sample JDBC program which retrieving user details.Now i am getting surprised that from same callable statement i am getting different result set for same output parameter index.Ideally it should return same ResultSet object.

1. when i got the resultset then i am moving cursor -1 to 0.
2. i am retrieving data from another resultset for the same output param using
       column name then i am getting following exception

,

***Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Missing defines***

```
 System.out.println("Before loading connection");
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@170.45.3.165:1541/testdb.mycomp.com",
            "admin", "admin123");
    System.out.println("Connection loaded " + connection);

    CallableStatement callProcedure = connection
            .prepareCall("{call ADMIN_USER.Fetch_User_Details(?,?)}");

    callProcedure.setString(1, "userid=testid");

    callProcedure.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    callProcedure.execute();

    ResultSet resultUserDetails = (ResultSet) callProcedure.getObject(2);
    resultUserDetails.next();

    ResultSet resultUserDetails1 = (ResultSet) callProcedure.getObject(2);
    String username = resultUserDetails1.getString(COL_NAME_USER_NAME);

    System.out.println(resultUserDetails);
    System.out.println(resultUserDetails1);

    System.out.println(resultUserDetails == resultUserDetails1);
```

**Can anyone has any idea why we are getting two different resultset for same output index from callable statement?**

Answer (score 0):

According to CallableSatement API  the expression should be like this

```
 {call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}
```

try

```
CallableStatement callProcedure = connection.prepareCall("{call ADMIN_USER.Fetch_User_Details(?,?)}");
```

Comment: The database specific method of executing a stored procedure is also allowed (you are not required to use the JDBC `call`-escape. [`CALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4008.htm#BABDEHHG) is the Oracle method of executing stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check if only reference are different (maybe due to proxy or dirty state because you perform a `next()` before the second `getObject())?
try

```
ResultSet resultUserDetails = (ResultSet) callProcedure.getObject(2);
ResultSet resultUserDetails1 = (ResultSet) callProcedure.getObject(2);

System.out.println(resultUserDetails);
System.out.println(resultUserDetails1);
//  Check ref or object equality
System.out.println(resultUserDetails == resultUserDetails1);
System.out.println(resultUserDetails.equals(resultUserDetails1));

resultUserDetails.next();
String username = resultUserDetails.getString(COL_NAME_USER_NAME);
resultUserDetails1.next();
String username1 = resultUserDetails1.getString(COL_NAME_USER_NAME);
System.out.println(username);
System.out.println(username1);
// We read the same username or we are reading first and second username?
// If the are different probably resultset is the same, just with different
// reference
System.out.println(resultUserDetails.equals(resultUserDetails1));
```

Comment: Hi Bellabax,I tried above thing however object equality(==) result was getting FALSE.Also when tried to get fetch col using 2nd reference then you would get exception.I wrote the code by considering that they were pointing to same object on heap.but both reference are pointing to different object.

Comment: ops, my fault! Exception is throwed because you are reading same columns twice (my mistake on `String username = resultUserDetails1.getString(COL_NAME_USER_NAME);`!).  Check the new code and write to comment System.out result